# Can I install npm packages without cding into the package directory?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I've tried `npm install <folder>`.
The problem is that this command will install packages into the current directory rather than the target `<folder>` directory.

Can I install packages into the `<folder>` directory without cding into it?

Comment: The meaning of `npm install <folder>` is to install whatever package is located at `<folder>` into the current working directory. `npm` always works on the current working directory (unless you perform global commands I guess).

Comment: This should help you: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install